# getent passwd fails, getent group works?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, opensuse, nss, nsswitch.conf

I've almost got my AD integration working completely on my OpenSUSE 12.1 server. I have a OpenSUSE 11.4 system successfully integrated into our AD environment. (Meaning, we use LDAP to authenticate to AD directory via Kerberos, so we can login to our *nix systems via AD users, using name service caching daemon to cache our passwords and groups).

Also, important to note these systems are in our LAN, SSL authentication is disabled.

I am almost all the way there. `nss_ldap` is finally authenticating with LDAP server (as `/var/log/messages` shows), but right now, I have another problem:

`getent passwd` and `getent shadow` fails (shows local accounts only), but `getent group` works! `getent group` shows all my ad groups!

I copied over the relavent configuration files from my working OpenSUSE 11.4 box:

```
 /etc/krb5.conf
 /etc/nsswitch.conf
 /etc/nscd.conf
 /etc/samba/smb.conf
 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
 /etc/pam.d/common-session-pc
 /etc/pam.d/common-account-pc
 /etc/pam.d/common-auth-pc
 /etc/pam.d/common-password-pc
```

I didn't modify anything between the two. I really don't think I need to modify anything, because getent passwd, getent shadow, and getent group all works fine on the OpenSUSE11.4 box.

Attempting to restart nscd service unfortunately didn't do much, and niether did running `/usr/sbin/nscd -i passwd`.

Do any of you admin-gurus have any suggestions?

Honestly, I'm happy I made it this far. I'm almost there guys!

Answer (score 3):

With regards to `getent passwd`/`shadow` its most likely configuration differences in the `/etc/switch.conf` file.
You might be using the following rule, which your client doesn't like.

```
passwd: compat
shodow: compat

passwd_compat:  ldap
shadow_compat:  ldap
```

Iv seen this on some of my clients where i needed to change it to the following

```
passwd: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
```

( comment out "**passwd_compat: ldap**" and "**shadow_compat: ldap**" )

Something you might want to try.

Comment: Tman, you are so awesome, that did it! :) I can now succesfully login using AD credentials.